# SAS append different file type

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have 2 file first csv and second txt like

```
text.txt     text.csv
1 eee        1,b1,c1
2 rff        2,b2,c2
3 r3r        3,b3,c3
4 344
```

Output dataset

```
1 eee        
2 rff        
3 r3r        
4 344
1 b1 c1
3 b3 c3
```

Can we do it in single data step in sas?

Comment: Are you trying to create a SAS dataset?  if so then what are the variables you want to create? What are their names? types? lengths?

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are looking for:

```
proc import datafile="text.txt" out=txt dbms=tab replace;
   getnames=no;
run;

proc import datafile="your_path/text.csv" out=csv dbms=csv replace;
    getnames=no;
run;

data want;
set txt csv;
run;
```